# How to get the highest value in array by key

Tags: php

So i have i big array and i want to get the highest value for each key, this is a demo of my output array :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [c__agency] => agency 10 
        [c__code] => code 10 
        [c__lifo] => lifo 10 
        [c__magasin] => 
        [c__mass] => 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [c__agency] => agency 1 
        [c__code] => code 1 
        [c__lifo] => lifo 1 
        [c__magasin] => 
        [c__mass] => 
    )
)
```

The result should be something like this : c__agency => 9 (count of agency 10) and so on for other keys.
So please if someone has any idea i will be very appreciative.

Comment: What would be the expected output here?

Comment: list of keys that has the biggest values

Comment: First iterate through all the subarrays and create a new array with the key being the main-key (eg. `0` and `1`) and the values being the `c__agency` values (so your array would end up being `array(0 => 'agency 10', 1 => 'agency 1')` - you can then sort this however you want.

Comment: if i do this i will lose the index

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: If you transform your array into something like this: `$array = array('0-c__agency' => 'agency 10', '1-c__agency' => 'agency 1')` Then you can use `array_count_values($array);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your concern i created an example for you. I hope it help you:-

```
<?php

$array = Array ( 
    '0' => Array ( 
        'c__agency' => 'agency 10', 
        'c__code' => 'code 10', 
        'c__lifo' => 'lifo 10',
        'c__magasin' => '',
        'c__mass' => ''
    ),
    '1' => Array ( 
        'c__agency' => 'agency 1', 
        'c__code' => 'code 1', 
        'c__lifo' => 'lifo 1', 
        'c__magasin' => '',
        'c__mass' => ''
    ),
    '2' => Array ( 
        'c__agency' => 'agency 12', 
        'c__code' => 'code 1', 
        'c__lifo' => 'lifo 1', 
        'c__magasin' => '',
        'c__mass' => ''
    )
);
echo "<pre/>";print_r($array); // print original array
array_multisort($array); // sort multi-dimensional array value-wise
echo "<pre/>";print_r(end($array)); // get the highest value array
$highest_value_data = end($array);  // assignment of highest value array to a variable
echo $highest_value_data['c__agency']; // get highest value of `c__agency`
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/547843

Answer (score -1):

Try Below Code:

```
$array = Array ( 
    '0' => Array ( 
        'c__agency' => 'agency 10', 
        'c__code' => 'code 10', 
        'c__lifo' => 'lifo 10',
        'c__magasin' => '',
        'c__mass' => ''
    ),
    '1' => Array ( 
        'c__agency' => 'agency 1', 
        'c__code' => 'code 1', 
        'c__lifo' => 'lifo 1', 
        'c__magasin' => '',
        'c__mass' => ''
    ),
    '2' => Array ( 
        'c__agency' => 'agency 12', 
        'c__code' => 'code 1', 
        'c__lifo' => 'lifo 1', 
        'c__magasin' => '',
        'c__mass' => ''
    )
);

print "<pre>";
print_r(end($array));
```

Comment: Are you serious? read user question. you just copy past my array and code. Man i created it as an example and before copy paste did you checked why i did that and whats  going on?